# redirect internet request to specific url

Tags: linux, iptables, redirect

in gateway base on linux how can redirect all internet accesses to port 80 in gateway. (any internet request redirect to port 80 in gateway).

can do this by iptables? or any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this? It seems like a fundamentally bad idea. It would go against every known standard of expected operation that exists.

That said, you could do this using the `PREROUTING` chain in iptables. These rules will work for the following assumptions:

- eth0 is your public interface
- You only need TCP redirected
- Your public IP address is 192.1.1.1
- You only want to redirect ports 1 through 65535

Rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dst 192.1.1.1 --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

Comment: He may just mean all http traffic redirected to the gateway.

Comment: looks like mikrotik hotspot, i want to redirect all internet request to a local webserver.